# How to remove whitespaces from a list of key-values?

Tags: ansible

How do I remove whitespaces from my list? The spaces are within the quotation marks, before and after the values.

```
    "Sales": [
        {
            "Category": " Toys ",
            "NumberSold": " 101 ",
            "ItemNumber": "#30",
            "Area": " West "
        },
        {
            "Category": " Toys ",
            "NumberSold": " 350 ",
            "ItemNumber": "#40",
            "Area": " South "
        },
        {
            "Category": " Toys ",
            "NumberSold": " 200 ",
            "ItemNumber": "#6",
            "Area": " East "
        }
    ]
```

Using the trim filter, I tried these combinations to remove the whitespaces, but all the whitespaces are still there:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ Sales | json_query('[].values(@)') | trim }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ Sales | json_query('[].values(@)') | map('trim',' ') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ Sales | json_query('[].values(@)') | map('trim') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ Sales | map('regex_replace', '^\\s+|\\s+$', '') }}"
```

I also tried separating the list's keys and values, and tested the same combinations again,

```
    - set_fact:
        Sales_keys: "{{ Sales | json_query('[].keys(@)') }}"

    - set_fact:
        Sales_values: "{{ Sales | json_query('[].values(@)') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ Sales_values | trim }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ Sales_values | map('trim',' ') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ Sales_values | map('trim') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ Sales_values | map('regex_replace', '^\\s+|\\s+$', '') }}"
```

but still not a single whitespace is removed.

P.S. Please do not provide solutions that contain '**{% filter from_yaml %} {% endfilter %}**' as it will result in an error on Ansible Automation Platform.

For e.g.

```
    - set_fact:
        userdata: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for i in userdata %}
          {% set keys=i.keys()|map('trim') %}
          {% set vals=i.values()|map('trim') %}
          - {{ dict(keys|zip(vals)) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a loop and `set_fact`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    Sales: [
        {
            "Category": " Toys ",
            "NumberSold": " 101 ",
            "ItemNumber": "#30",
            "Area": " West "
        },
        {
            "Category": " Toys ",
            "NumberSold": " 350 ",
            "ItemNumber": "#40",
            "Area": " South "
        },
        {
            "Category": " Toys ",
            "NumberSold": " 200 ",
            "ItemNumber": "#6",
            "Area": " East "
        }
    ]
  tasks:
    - loop: "{{ Sales }}"
      set_fact:
        New_Sales: >-
          {{
            New_Sales + [
              dict(item.keys()|zip(item.values()|map("trim")))
            ]
          }}
      vars:
        New_Sales: []

    - debug:
        var: New_Sales
```

Running the above playbooks produces:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'Category': ' Toys ', 'NumberSold': ' 101 ', 'ItemNumber': '#30', 'Area': ' West '})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'Category': ' Toys ', 'NumberSold': ' 350 ', 'ItemNumber': '#40', 'Area': ' South '})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'Category': ' Toys ', 'NumberSold': ' 200 ', 'ItemNumber': '#6', 'Area': ' East '})

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "New_Sales": [
        {
            "Area": "West",
            "Category": "Toys",
            "ItemNumber": "#30",
            "NumberSold": "101"
        },
        {
            "Area": "South",
            "Category": "Toys",
            "ItemNumber": "#40",
            "NumberSold": "350"
        },
        {
            "Area": "East",
            "Category": "Toys",
            "ItemNumber": "#6",
            "NumberSold": "200"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```